# Is there no point to make a 1 length long var char in database?

Tags: mysql, memory, char, varchar

I would like to store a user status in the database, so, I will use a char to store the status, for example, "active", "inactive", "close". I will use "a", "i", "c" to represent these status. But it is non-sense to store a varchar in database? should I use a char type or set?

****the database in mysql.

Comment: **varchar** is short for "Variable Character"... If it won't variate in size, there is no need to use varchar, that is slower and bigger than **char**. At other hand, *c*, *i*, etc have no real meaning. Use semantics, (I think that) *Active* is better than *a*.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider using an int or an [enum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) instead.  If you do want a char type, CHAR(1) NOT NULL should be fine.  With an enum, it would be:

```
status ENUM('active', 'inactive', 'close')
```

With an int:

```
status tinyint
```

Using an int is a good option, but *document* the values well.

Comment: Even better: `ENUM('active', 'inactive', 'close')`. The storage size does not change.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to beware of is that adding a new value to an enum requires rewriting the entire table. I generally recommend storing CHAR or VARCHAR. One can add a FK reference to a table of legal values if you want an other aspect of enums, that of requiring the value to be a listed one. Then the 'almost enum' can be extended by adding another value to the FK'ed table.